# Picture animation stops midway through

Tags: css

Wasnt sure what to write in the title, so sorry if its misleading someone.

At a earlier post I asked how I could make a div only visible between two dates, the answer I got works but thats not the problem. Now I want the same div (and the pictures it uses) to have the same height of the page it is on. The height is set too 100% but that whould just make the picture 100% and not the div it self. This makes the picture (animation) stop midway through and look stupid.

How can I make the height automatically adjust according to the page height?

CSS:

```
#snow{
  background: none;
  font-family: Androgyne;
  background-image: url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img/s1.png'), url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img//s2.png'), url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img//s3.png');
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:9999;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
  animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 400px 1000px, 200px 400px, 100px 300px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;}
} 

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #snow {
    display:none;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 720px) {
  #snow {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Use `id="snow"` to display the snow effect

```
<div id="snow"></div>
```

To easier understand, heres a codepen http://codepen.io/Volcan3/pen/ENPpPN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height: 100%` actually means setting the height of this element to **100% of it's containing element**.

You can read the details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is relative to the initial containing block.

You should make sure the parent element of your `<div id="snow"></div>` block is properly styled.

Please feel free to comment if this doesn't solve your problem.

UPDATE:

The problem with your code is:

The parent element of `#snow` is `.snow-wrapper`, the parent of `.snow-wrapper` is `body`.

`#snow` has style `position: absolute; height: 100%`, which you intend to be calculated from `.snow-wrapper`'s height.

Let's look at `.snow-wrapper`. It has style `height:100%;`. However, it is not absolutely positioned, and it's parent (`body`) doesn't have a explicitly set height.

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto.

You should inspect `.snow-wrapper` and will find out that it's computed height is 0.

One way to make this codepen instance work is to make body relatively positioned.

```
// From:
body { background-color:#333; }
// To:
body { background-color:#333; position:relative; }
```

This is just a quick fix.

You should do more research on related topics. Try `document flow`, `flex layout`, `clearfix` and other keywords on google.

Comment: not sure if i understand, I have updated the question with a codepen, could you take a look?

Comment: @martinj I updated my answer. Added a quick fix and pointed out some leads. Please accept if it solves your problem :D